# Correct way to bind lists of lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am out putting a dynamic form that has groupings of custom fields

So on my main Form(Form) object I have a list of Groupings(Group), these groupings have a list of custom fields(Field) each, the groupings are mainly used for displaying the custom fields into columns with headings etc.

My problem is that for each new grouping I display the counter for the custom fields resets and goes back to 0, this means that when it comes to the data being posted back to my controller things don't post correctly because there are duplicate name attributes.

I am currently posing back a list of the fields as I don't need to post back the groupings.

Does anyone have any solutions of different ways I could do this? This I am obviously doing wrong?

In this example code below the HTML produced for this form gives me 4 input controls, but only two unique control names, e.g. two controls have "name="group.Fields[0].Result"" for the name attribute, and the other two have "name="group.Fields[1].Result"", which when posted back to the controller will obviously not work.

Edit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FieldsPoC.Models;

namespace FieldsPoC.Controllers
{
    public class FormController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            FormViewModel model = new FormViewModel();

            var group = new GroupViewModel();
            group.Label = "Group 1";
            group.Fields.Add(new FieldViewModel() { Label = "Field 1", Type = FieldType.Number });
            group.Fields.Add(new FieldViewModel() { Label = "Field 2", Type = FieldType.Text });
            model.Groups.Add(group);

            group = new GroupViewModel();
            group.Label = "Group 2";
            group.Fields.Add(new FieldViewModel() { Label = "Field 1", Type = FieldType.DateTime });
            group.Fields.Add(new FieldViewModel() { Label = "Field 2", Type = FieldType.Number });
            model.Groups.Add(group);

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Contact")]ContactViewModel contact, List<GroupViewModel> fields)
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
}

namespace FieldsPoC.Models
{
    public class ContactViewModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace FieldsPoC.Models
{
    public class ContactViewModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace FieldsPoC.Models
{
    public class GroupViewModel
    {
        public GroupViewModel()
        {
            Fields = new List<FieldViewModel>();
        }

        // Other layout properties
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public List<FieldViewModel> Fields { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace FieldsPoC.Models
{
    public enum FieldType
    {
        Text = 0,
        Number = 1,
        DateTime = 2
    }

    public class FieldViewModel
    {
        public FieldType Type { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

FormIndex:

```
@model FieldsPoC.Models.FormViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("", "Form"))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact)

            foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
            {
            @Html.EditorFor(x => group);
            }

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EditorTemplates:

```
@model FieldsPoC.Models.ContactViewModel
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>

@model FieldsPoC.Models.FieldViewModel
<div class="editor-label">
   @Model.Label
</div>

@{ 
    switch (Model.Type)
    {
        case FieldsPoC.Models.FieldType.DateTime:
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Result);
            break;
        case FieldsPoC.Models.FieldType.Number:
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Result);
            break;
        case FieldsPoC.Models.FieldType.Text:
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Result);
            break;
    }
}

@model FieldsPoC.Models.GroupViewModel
<fieldset>
    <legend>@Model.Label</legend>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fields)
</fieldset>
```

### Heading

Comment: Can you show us some code? Are you using Html Helpers? you can always go to manually setting the name attribute.
Are you using a ViewModel for the view (I highly recommend you do if you aren't for this kind of scenario.)

Comment: I was thinking that manually setting the name attribute might be the way to go but then I would need unique ids for the fields across various groups right?

Comment: When I did my edit, I don't know where the "Heading" bit at the very end came from.  It's not in my Notepad++ window anywhere.  Did two edits get confused or something?